# How to create an AMP page only for the specified category?

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I want to create AMP pages for posts in a category that I just want, instead of the pages or articles in the entire site.

I've tried a few add-ons. These add-ons create an AMP page for all pages and articles.

I just want to add AMP support to a category I want.

Is there a plugin that you would suggest for this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for plugins or software are off topic for this site. Please see [What topics can I ask about?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to find out more about what you can ask about.

Comment: @fatihtoprak which plugin are you using? you need to put the check on non amp pages for specific category.

Comment: its automattic amp plugin @BachchaSingh

Comment: @FatihToprak you have to create custom plugin

Comment: its okey i can do it but there is no document actually i could not find any docs about hooks / actions for this (if its) can you offer some docs if you have any idea. ? 

Or if its possible can you describe any methıod, action or hooks for this actions.